# Including controller when routing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I'm building a fairly large single page web app with AngularJS and I'm trying to find the best way to make it very modular.

I'm using `ngRoute` to build my routes, my `app.js` contains:

```
...
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/stats', {
        templateUrl : 'views/stats.html',
        controller  : 'StatController'
    })
    ...
```

In order for this to work I need to include my `StatController` on my main `index.html` file as well as including `app.js`.

```
<script src="/js/StatController.js"></script>
```

Seems reasonable when I include just 1 or 2 controller, but what if I have 30 controllers? do I still have to include them all in my `index.html` page or is there a way for Angular to include it only when it's needed (i.e., when requesting a new controller)

Comment: I would recommend keeping a single file called `controllers.js` instead of keeping different files for each controller.

Comment: I am also working on such project but i have separated it out and used grunt to concatenate the JS files. Now, my index.html has only app.js (excluding library). For folder structure, i referred https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

Comment: @iJade  @VigneswaranMarimuthu so the `controllers.js` file will get pretty large, is there no better way to modularise it without having to concatenate files?

Comment: This might help [link](http://artandlogic.com/2013/05/ive-been-doing-it-wrong-part-1-of-3/)

Comment: @matt When you develop, it will be in separate files. But while testing it will be huge. Since, you don't want to include those files in HTML, you need to concatenate all JS files to one (called `app.js`), using some task runner (I use GRUNT). If you are fine with including the JS file references in HTML, then you can check at `grunt-usemin` for optimizing those file references

Comment: Using TypeScript (and modules) might be another good option https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Modules - Angular and TypeScript is a nice combination anyway, not only for your specific issue.

Comment: It's normal to import all of your js files in your index. There is no way to detect dynamically if this controller is using so inject this specific file. But you just need to use a tool to optimize your imports with Grunt or Gulp for production only. When I say optimize, I mean concatenate all files in only one.

Answer (score 0):

Each view has attached a controller if you need some logic on the current view. The best practice is to separate features of your app in small pieces of routing file.For example you have to create a account section.You can create a `accountRoute.js` where you have you're module, like so :

```
angular.module('myModule').config(function ($stateProvider){
.state('someName',{/*add controllers templates here*/})
})
```

and other states maybe.
If you need to create another future, for example dashboard, you can create another routing file, `dashboardRoute.js`, where you use the same angular module.This is a good practice to structure you're code to be more clean.
So in `dashboardRoute.js` you will have:

```
angular.module('myModule').config(function ($stateProvider){
    .state('anotherStateName',{/*add controllers templates here for dashboard feature*/})
    })
```

All routes will be injected in the same module, so you will have access to them.
Last but not least, you should have also a `app.js` file where you inject all you're module dependency needed, login routing and so on.
 In my opinion a `controllers.js` file is hard to debug, maintain and read. Each controller should be separated in a different `.js` file and added on `index.html`.
I hope it helped.